# Determine whether the selected video is .MOV or .MP4 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my application, i need to select mp4 video file from iPhone Gallery  and upload it on server.Is it possible to check whether the selected file is .mp4 or .mov?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the file extension from the below snippet

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    NSString *mediaType =   [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType]; 

    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
      {        
        NSString * videoURL=info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
        NSString *lastPath = [videoURL lastPathComponent];
        NSString *fileExtension = [lastPath pathExtension];
        NSLog(@"File extension %@",fileExtension);


      }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No we cant read it there by selecting.once you selected it, that file will came in to your app there you decode to NSdata and encode it back.in between this process there is a chance to find out.try this method, Hope this will work.